# Change of variables in higher dimension

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The specific question I am interested in is the following:

$\int_{x_2}^1 dx_1 \int_{x_3}^1 dx_2 \cdots \int_{x_{n+1}}^1dx_n \int_0^1 dx_{n+1}f_1(1-x_1)\cdots f_{n+1}(x_n-x_{n+1})$

and doing the change of variables:

$\tilde x_i = x_{i-1}-x_i \quad \forall i = 1,\dots, n+1$

where $x_0 = 1$. There is no problem calculating the Jacobian, but I can't figure out the boundaries for the $\tilde x_i$. So my question I guess is more general, I know the theory of how to do change of variables, so I "just" have to take the image of the domain, but already in this relatively simple case of a linear transformation, I don't know how to do it in practice. Is there a way to make this mechanic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have of thinking about this is to write down the region of integration in terms of inequalities, then rearrange them to get inequalities for the new variables. Assuming what you actually mean is
$$ \int_0^1 \int_{x_{n+1}}^{1} \dotsi \int_{x_3}^1 \int_{x_2}^{1} dx_1 \, dx_2 \dotsm \, dx_n \, dx_{n+1}, $$
so that each integral only depends on the variables inside it, the region of integration is
$$ 1>x_{1}>x_2>x_3 > \dotsb > x_n > x_{n+1} > 0, $$
which you can see by looking at each integral separately.

---

On the other hand, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that substitution, since the inner integral is obviously $(1-x_2)$, then the next one is $-(1-x_3)^2/2$, and so on until you get to $-(1-x_{n+1})^n/n!$ and finally $1/(n+1)!$.

Comment: Yes, so this inequality is exactly from what I started, but I am not entirely sure that gives the integration boundaries for the $\tilde x$, and maybe I should have specified there is of course a function of the $\tilde x$ in the integral which is why I am doing that change of variables.